# How to get armadillo with MKL to use multiple threads for vector multiplication?

Tags: c++, multithreading, armadillo, intel-mkl

I am multiplying vectors and matrices, generated with armadillo. Armadillo was compiled and linked with the Intel MKL. Now I would like to get my program to use more than only one thread for the multiplication. 
I tried setting

```
omp_set_max_threads(4)
```

and

```
mkl_set_max_threads(4)
```

but both still keep the program at one thread, not four. Are there any other ways to increase the amount of threads?
The code I use for multiplication is

```
void multiply(const arma::cx_colvec &in, arma::cx_colvec &out)
{
    //F, G= arma::cx_colvec, rb, br = arma::colvec
    if(out.size() != in.size())
        out = arma::cx_colvec(in.size());
    F = in % (rb);
    G = c * F;
    out = G % (br);
}
```

Comment: have you tried to use `mkl_set_num_threads` in combination with `mkl_set_dynamic`?

Comment: Yes, it does not help

Comment: and what is the typical size of those vectors? the MKL library does the threading "on-the-fly" so it might "decide" that the sizes/dimensions are such that the overhead of starting the threaded calculation might not be worth the potential gain...

Comment: >1000 elements, usually